# In Java, are variables declared inside static methods themselves static?

Tags: java, static

Assume the following:

```
private static boolean A()
{
  int parsedUntil = 0;
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Is parsedUntil considered to be a static variable? I noticed that I can't declare it as static inside this static function.

Follow-up question: I read that a static variable will only be initialized once. Does that mean the first time I call function A() the value will be set to zero, but every other time I call A(), that row is omitted?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it's not a static variable. It's a local variable. Any variable declared in a method is a local variable. If you want a static variable, you have to declare it outside the method:

```
private static int parsedUntil = 0;
```

There's no way of declaring a static variable which can only be used within a single method.

Comment: It's all about scope.  The scope is local to the method, regardless of the method type.

Comment: @Robin: No, it's about lifetime. In other langauges, "static locals" can have a single-method scope but static lifetime, which is sometimes useful; in both cases the scope is local to the method, but the lifetime is different.

Comment: I read that, "A static method can access only static data. It cannot access non-static data (instance variables)" then how come `parsedUntil` being a non-static variable be accessible from a static function?

Comment: @SaurabhRana: Assuming you mean `parsedUntil` in the original question (rather than in my answer) that's a local variable, not an instance variable. I don't know where you got that exact sentence from, but it's not the way I'd have written it.

Comment: @JonSkeet makes sense. So static methods can 'access' other static methods and variables, but of course static methods can have local variables. `parsedUntil` is a local variables in the static method.

Answer (score 6):

no, `A()` is a static method, and `parsedUntil` is a local variable inside A.

Modifiers like `static` are not valid in local variables (only `final` is permitted afaik)

> Follow-up question: I read that a
>   static variable will only be
>   initialized once.

true

> Does that mean the
>   first time I call function A() the
>   value will be set to zero, but every
>   other time I call A(), that row is
>   omitted?

since parsedUntil is not a static field, but a local variable in a static method, this is not the case.

Comment: But what would it mean if I declared it as final inside the function? Regarding classes I read that the final keyword means that the functions of such a class, cannot be overloaded by subclasses. (Perhaps such classes cannot even be extended!?)

Comment: in local variables, final means that the variable can't be re-assigned

Answer (score 5):

`static` variables cannot be declared locally inside methods - they can only be members of a class, and they get initialised when the class is loaded.

Comment: Thanks! When you say that they can only be members of a class I remember that I have read that and it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have static local variables like C or C++ does, so you can never have `static int parsedUtil = 0;`.

So no, `parsedUtil` is not in any sense "static".  Its value is initialised to 0 every time the method is executed.

Comment: Local variables are NOT initialised in Java.

Comment: @Ian - According to the JLS 14.4.2: "*If a [local variable] declarator has an initializer, the initializer is evaluated and its value is assigned to the variable.*"  That's close enough for me ;)

Comment: Fair point.  But, unlike variables at the class or instance scope Java performs no initialization by **default**.  That was the point I was trying to make, though rereading your answer I see it doesn't actually apply in this case.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not C.

parsedUntil  is not static. It's just a local variable. You cannot declare static variable inside the method.

Regarding second question - static variables can be assigned as many times as you want. You cannot reassign only final variables.