# Static methods for reading/writing to database

Tags: java, database-connection, static-methods

I am currently using a number of static methods within a class to read data from a MySQL database. The following code is an example of one of these methods:

**DatabaseReader Class:**

```
public class DatabaseReader
{
    //Method to get an employee's details.
    public static JSONArray getEmployee(String employeeID)
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeeID = ?";
        DatabaseConnection dbc = new DatabaseConnection(query);
        dbc.setString(1, employeeID);
        return getResultsFromQuery(dbc);
    }

    //More static methods here...
    //...
    //...
}
```

So to call this method, I use the `DatabaseReader.getEmployee(employeeID);` statement within my code.

Based on the above, I understand that the `getEmployee()` method belongs to the `DatabaseReader` class instead of belonging to an instance of it (e.g. `DatabaseReader dbr = new DatabaseReader();` followed by `dbr.getEmployee(1);`).

I am not sure though if it is good practice to use static methods for database connectivity, since there will be multiple users using the same methods.

If there are two users using the `getEmployee()` method, would the `query` and `dbc` variables within the static method be static as well, and thus shared across both of these users? Or would each of these users be using their own separate instances of a `query` String and `dbc` DatabaseConnection?

Is it reasonable to use static methods (such as the one above) for reading/writing to a database?

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2671636/2310289) especially the comments

Comment: What do you mean users? Methods aren't called by people, they're called by other methods.

Comment: If two "users" call a *non-static* method do they share the same local variables? No they don't.

Answer (score 0):

"No, it's not a static variable. It's a local variable. Any variable declared in a method is a local variable." -Source: [In Java, are variables declared inside static methods themselves static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426117/in-java-are-variables-declared-inside-static-methods-themselves-static)

I think you're fine using static methods for database connections. I might encourage it in fact.